# How to transpose two arguments of a function in Python?

Tags: python, text-editing

How I can I swap two arguments in a call to a Python function?

If I put `point` on the space between these two arguments:

```
self.assertEqual(json.loads(some.data), json_data)
```

and then `M-t` (`transpose-words`), I get:

```
self.assertEqual(json.loads(some.json), data_data)
```

On the other hand with C-M-t (`transpose-sexps`) I get:

```
self.assertEqual(json.loadsjson_data, (some.data))
```

What I want is:

```
self.assertEqual(json_data, json.loads(some.data))
```

Is there a command that will do that?

Comment: I haven't tried but [Anchored Transpose](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/AnchoredTranspose) can be used for this; it's, though, a 2-step process.

Comment: There is a core function called `transpose-subr` which takes a `forward` function and translates it into a `transpose` function. So if we had `c-forward-arglist` (function to move from one function arg to the next - AFAICT this doesn't exist) we would have `c-transpose-arglist`.

Answer (score 5):

I use a variation of `transpose-sexps` that looks for the case you describe and transposes things-separated-by-commas, or just does regular `transpose-sexps`.  It also leaves the cursor in place instead of dragging it forward, which is a bit different but I personally like.

```lisp
(defun my-transpose-sexps ()
  "If point is after certain chars transpose chunks around that.
Otherwise transpose sexps."
  (interactive "*")
  (if (not (looking-back "[,]\\s-*" (point-at-bol)))
      (progn (transpose-sexps 1) (forward-sexp -1))
    (let ((beg (point)) end rhs lhs)
      (while (and (not (eobp))
                  (not (looking-at "\\s-*\\([,]\\|\\s)\\)")))
        (forward-sexp 1))
      (setq rhs (buffer-substring beg (point)))
      (delete-region beg (point))
      (re-search-backward "[,]\\s-*" nil t)
      (setq beg (point))
      (while (and (not (bobp))
                  (not (looking-back "\\([,]\\|\\s(\\)\\s-*" (point-at-bol))))
        (forward-sexp -1))
      (setq lhs (buffer-substring beg (point)))
      (delete-region beg (point))
      (insert rhs)
      (re-search-forward "[,]\\s-*" nil t)
      (save-excursion
        (insert lhs)))))
```

Comment: For me this leaves whitespace at the start of the assertEqual call (starting with point on the space).

Comment: This does not work for keyword arguments like: `f(a=1, b=2)` (it transposes around)

Comment: While the question is abount C code, this answer works for `f(a=1, b=2)` - https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/47930/2418

Answer (score 4):

This is something I, too, wanted to have for a long time, and here I've found some motivation to work on it.  It's probably not very robust, but at the first try it seems to cover the cases I tried:

```el
(defun my/calculate-stops ()
  (save-excursion
    (let ((start
           (condition-case e
               (while t (backward-sexp))
             (error (point))))
          stops)
      (push start stops)
      (condition-case e
          (while t
            (forward-sexp)
            (when (looking-at-p "\\s-*,")
              (push (point) stops)))
        (error (push (point) stops)))
      (nreverse stops))))

(defun my/transpose-args ()
  (interactive)
  (when (looking-at-p "\\s-") (backward-sexp))
  (cl-loop with p = (point)
           with previous = nil
           for stop on (my/calculate-stops)
           for i upfrom 0
           when (<= p (car stop)) do
           (when previous
             (let* ((end (cadr stop))
                    (whole (buffer-substring previous end))
                    middle last)
               (delete-region previous end)
               (goto-char previous)
               (setf middle (if (> i 1) (- (car stop) previous)
                              (string-match-p "[^, \\t]" whole 
                                              (- (car stop) previous)))
                     last (if (> i 1) (substring whole 0 middle)
                            (concat (substring whole (- (car stop) previous) middle)
                                    (substring whole 0 (- (car stop) previous)))))
               (insert (substring whole middle) last)))
           (cl-return)
           end do (setf previous (car stop))))
```

Comment: I get this when point is on the space (works when on the comma): let*: Wrong type argument: integer-or-marker-p, nil

Comment: @CroadLangshan the fix was relatively easy (see above). The funny thing I tried to follow Stefan's advise by writing an alternative `forward-sexp-function`, and that appeared to be too cumbersome because of the commas. I then tried to copycat `traspose-sexp` to do the same thing, and, again, having to account for commas makes this really difficult. I don't claim this always does the right thing when it comes to list delimiters, maybe only half of the time...

Comment: This fails for `(aa, bb)` when the cursor is on the first `a`. This also doesn't work for transposing `FOO(aaa *, bbb, ccc)` The `*` somehow messes up transposing.

Comment: Also fails for `FOO(&aaa, bbb)` (& doesn't swap).

Answer (score 2):

In modes that use SMIE, `transpose-sexp` should work correctly for that case.  They will still fail when the infix symbol (aka "separator") is not a `,` (or a `;`) but is a word (e.g. `and`).

So, my opinion is that the command for that is `transpose-sexp` and when this doesn't work correctly, I consider it as a bug (but a bug that may be hard and/or take time to fix and have low-priority, so don't hold your breath).  The way to fix it is by setting `forward-sexp-function` to a function that will know that "after I see a comma, I just jump around the whole argument".

Comment: I guess java-mode (for example) doesn't use SMIE?  How would one go about fixing that?

Comment: No, indeed, major modes for C-like languages don't use SMIE and not only for historical reasons: SMIE's parser is just too weak for those languages.  This said, SMIE's parser would work just fine if you want to swap two arguments separated by a comma (this part of the grammar is simple enough), so I guess it would be possible to configure SMIE and use it for `forward-sexp-function` but you'd have to add some code to only use SMIE's `forward-sexp-function`  in those cases where it works well enough, since in many other cases it would result in confusing behavior.