# Is there a way to move region with arrow keys or similar?

Tags: region, motion

Say I have a function

```c
int calc(int that, int this);
```

I want to mark `int that` and then move it right across words by hitting modifier arrow key (or similar) twice to get

```c
int calc(int this, int that);
```

This is left and right, but I'm also interested in moving lines or selected blocks up and down.

Comment: I used to know a command that did that...

Comment: Do you really mean to move whole lines, e.g. the lines touched by the region? If not, what does it mean to move a region forward - does it mean move it forward the same number of chars that it has?

Comment: FWIW: If your regions are paragraphs then `transpose-paragraphs` will do the job. Bind it to a key. You can use `M--` to move it backward.

Comment: There is a similar discussion here: [How to transpose two arguments of a function in Python?
](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/11061/how-to-transpose-two-arguments-of-a-function-in-python).

Comment: And [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/47930/53) is a nice function for transposing arguments.

Comment: So it seems the short answer is "not built in". Thank you for the links.

Comment: @Drew by move forward I mean once `int this` is marked, I can move the region forward one char at a time with arrow keys or `C-f` or one word at a time with `M-f`, putting whatever it hits behind it.